# Why are my maple leaves just plain green after transplanting?

Tags: leaves, maple

I had three maples in the garden in my last home and they had lovely (non-green) coloured leaves on them there. I have now replanted them in my new home and all I get now is just green leaves.

Why don't they have the colour they used to have?

Comment: How long since you replanted them? Any chance of a photograph or two?

Comment: What time of year was it when you moved them?  How old are these trees, how large?  Are these Japanese Maples?

Comment: Japanese maples can have gorgeous reds and purple leaves both spring with the new growth and fall.  During the summer they are green.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [article](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/red-dragon-japanese-maple-mostly-green-98496.html) on the net describing the causes of similar behaving of maple color.

It basically says that japanese maples may become more 'green' if:

- there is environmental impact
- there is not enough light
- there Is some growth directly from rootstock
- the tree is under stress

---

Seattle Japanese Garden also offers a very good [article '*Gardeners' Talk: Autumn Colors and Japanese Maples*'](https://www.seattlejapanesegarden.org/blog/2017/10/13/gardeners-talk-autumn-colors-and-japanese-maples)on maple autumn colors. Key point:

> The brilliance of color is thought to be most affected by temperature,
>   light, and soil moisture, not just fall but all through the growing
>   season. It is suggested that an ideal combination would be a wet warm
>   spring, a summer that is not too dry, and an autumn filled with dry
>   days and cool nights.